# jupyterlab - change styling - font, font size

Tags: python, css, jupyter-lab

I recently updated to the most recent version of JupyterLab (0.28.12). I'm on Windows.

I've tried adjusting the `variables.css` file located in `\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension` of my Miniconda/Anaconda folder. I mainly want to change the font family and size, which I've tried using the `variables.css` file. However, I can't see any changes.

I went to the extreme point of deleting both theme folders, but still I can change themes without a problem through the Lab interface.

Where are the JupyterLab theme .css files located? Or how can I find them? I've searched for `css` files and the `themes` sub folder seems to be the only location for them. I can't seem to find any in my user directory either `c:\Users\User\.jupyter` where the `.css` files were for Jupyter Notebook were located.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I am running version 0.35.4 right now on Ubuntu and it is possible to edit the fonts in the Settings->Advanced Settings Editor, selected from the top bar menu.

There are a number of options that can be set by changing the json strings in the Raw View.  See the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It is now possible to change the font sizes of most elements of the interface via the `Settings` menu .e.g: `Settings`->`JupyterLab Theme`->`Increase Code Font Size` etc.

*Note:* These do **not** change if `View`->`Presentation Mode` is ticked.

To change the font style one still needs to go to `Settings`->`Advanced Settings Editor` (as mentioned in other answers) - and one can also changes font sizes there - which will take effect even if Presentation Mode is enabled.

Answer (score 8):

I'm on ubuntu, so probably have to adapt for windows. The fonts for cell-editing are available in the UI as noted by @vince-w. I just copied over a minimal set to my user settings.

```
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "fontFamily": "DejaVu Sans Mono",
        "fontSize": 15,
        "lineHeight": 1.2,
    },
    "markdownCellConfig": {
        "fontFamily": "M+ 2p",
        "fontSize": 16,
        "lineHeight": 1.2,
    },
    "rawCellConfig": {
        "fontFamily": "M+ 2p",
        "fontSize": 16,
        "lineHeight": 1.2,
    }
}
```

All good, except for the rendered markdown in the notebook. To fix that I found the css file in my conda env and modified it directly. Pretty much what @苗晧宇 noted. Change path for light/dark.

$HOME/anaconda3/envs/YOUR_ENV_NAME_HERE/share/jupyter/lab/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-dark-extension/index.css

```
  /*                       vvvv changed from 14px  */
  --jp-content-font-size1: 16px; /* Base font size */

  /*                        vvvv inserted at the front  */
  --jp-content-font-family: 'M+ 2p', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',
```

I tried creating a copy of that index.css file at $HOME/.jupyter/lab/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-dark-extension/index.css, but it was ignored by jupyterlab.

Answer (score 5):

From http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extensions.html?highlight=themes :

- The themes directory contains assets (such as CSS and icons) for JupyterLab theme extensions.
- The themes directory is located in the JupyterLab application directory which defaults to `<sys-prefix>/share/jupyter/lab`, where `<sys-prefix>` is the site-specific directory prefix of the current Python environment. You can query the current application path by running `jupyter lab path`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I was looking for a way to change font size but the two options i found are: change it current theme or create new custom theme.

Comment: I believe now there are options to change the `font-family` and `font-size` in the Advanced settings?

Comment: is there any settings for terminal fonts, can't seem to find it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter deskotp version latest 3.6.1 .

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should change the font size in the website. It should be at `Settings->Fonts->Code->Size` for code editor and `Settings->Fonts->Content->Size` for main contents
The css file should be `<prefix>/share/jupyter/lab/themes/@jupyterlab/<your theme>/index.css`.
To change the font, find all the place in the css file which looks like setting font, and change it.

Answer (score 0):

For increasing the font size on JupyterLabs:

1. Click: Settings > Theme > Increase Code Font Size