# How to change the font of output cells in jupyter lab

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want code for changing the font of the output cells in jupyter-lab.
I hope to help me for this problem.
I tried this code

```
%%html
<style>
.jp-Output-cell { font-size: 25px; }
</style>
```

but it is not working.
I appreciate your efforts.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please cite the source of the code you tried as it looks like you are trying things meant to work in older Jupyter Notebook and not JupyterLab. What have you tried specific to JupyterLab? There's Settings you can change. The Settings editor may not be accessed  in the same place referenced in [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53771778/8508004). As spelled out [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-fonts-data-driven-style-and-typography-for-jupyterlab/10363?u=fomightez), "JupyterLab 3 natively supports using already-installed fonts and tuning a few parameters."

Comment: <continued> Specifically, changing the settings for font in a more recent version of JupyterLab is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048278/jupyterlab-change-styling-font-font-size/54520440#54520440).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.